# ES Module error encountered when testing npm package locally

Tags: es6-modules, commonjs, remix, esbuild, esmodules

#### Background:

I am trying to test an npm package that I am developing: a React Component that manages a SVG filter animation. In verifying that it works as expected, I have used `npm pack` to generate a tarball, which I have then installed as a dependency in another project (one I expect to consume said package when properly published).

To make this easier, I will refer to the npm package I am developing as `package A` and refer to the project that consumes it as `project B`. Please take note of the technologies mentioned below as their giving context will likely provide insight.

##### Relevant Technologies

###### packageA

- node: 14.18.1
- esbuild: ^0.11.11
- typescript: ^4.2.3

###### projectB

- node: 14.18.1
- remix: 1.4.1
- typescript: ^4.2.3

#### Observations + Problems:

- **Observations:**

  - `npm pack`, when run in `package A`, spits out a tarball that includes everything BUT the output build directory of `package A`.
  - `package A` has a package.json with a *type* field set as *"module"*, thereby declaratively supporting ES Module System syntax.
  - `npm install` of this tarball in `project B` is successful.
  - If I change my import of `package A` to its absolute path (node_modules/projectA/build/main.js) in `project B`'s node_modules I avoid the problem defined in Problems #1.
- **Problems:**

  1. Any attempt to consume `package A` in `project B` is met with the following error:

```
// THIS IMPORT

// projectB > index.js
import PackageAComponent from 'packageA'

// RESULTS IN:

     throw new ERR_REQUIRE_ESM(filename, parentPath, packageJsonPath);
      ^

Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module: /Users/jackwilliammorris/Code/better-brain-blogging/node_modules/fuzzy-scrawl/build/esbuild/browser.js
require() of ES modules is not supported.
require() of /Users/jackwilliammorris/Code/better-brain-blogging/node_modules/fuzzy-scrawl/build/esbuild/browser.js from /Users/jackwilliammorris/Code/better-brain-blogging/server/index.js is an ES module file as it is a .js file whose nearest parent package.json contains "type": "module" which defines all .js files in that package scope as ES modules.
Instead rename browser.js to end in .cjs, change the requiring code to use import(), or remove "type": "module" from /Users/jackwilliammorris/Code/better-brain-blogging/node_modules/fuzzy-scrawl/package.json.

    at new NodeError (internal/errors.js:322:7)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1102:13)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:93:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/jackwilliammorris/Code/better-brain-blogging/app/routes/braindumps/index.tsx:8:25)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
```

#### Relevant Code Snippets

```json
// projectB package.json
{
  "name": "projectB",
  "private": true,
  "description": "",
  "license": "",
  "sideEffects": false,
  "scripts": {
    ... ,
    "dev": "run-p dev:*",
    "dev:arc": "node ./dev sandbox",
    "dev:css": "npm run generate:css -- --watch",
    "dev:remix": "remix watch",
    ...
  },
  "prettier": {},
  "dependencies": {
    "@architect/architect": "^10.2.1",
    "@architect/functions": "^5.0.4",
    "@happy-dom/jest-environment": "^3.1.0",
    "@notionhq/client": "^1.0.4",
    "@remix-run/architect": "^1.4.1",
    "@remix-run/node": "^1.4.1",
    "@remix-run/react": "^1.4.1",
    "@remix-run/server-runtime": "^1.4.1",
    "bcryptjs": "2.4.3",
    "classnames": "^2.3.1",
    "cuid": "^2.1.8",
    "fuzzy-scrawl": "file:../fuzzy-scrawl/fuzzy-scrawl-0.0.0.tgz",
    "highlight.js": "^11.5.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "tiny-invariant": "^1.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@faker-js/faker": "^6.1.1",
    "@remix-run/dev": "^1.4.1",
    "@remix-run/eslint-config": "^1.4.1",
    "@testing-library/cypress": "^8.0.2",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.3",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.4",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.0.4",
    "@types/architect__functions": "^3.13.6",
    "@types/bcryptjs": "2.4.2",
    "@types/eslint": "^8.4.1",
    "@types/jest": "^27.4.1",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.43",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.14",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^1.3.0",
    "c8": "^7.11.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "cypress": "^9.5.3",
    "esbuild": "^0.14.29",
    "eslint": "^8.12.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "happy-dom": "^2.55.0",
    "jest": "^27.5.1",
    "mock-aws-s3": "^4.0.2",
    "msw": "^0.39.2",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "prettier": "^2.6.1",
    "prettier-plugin-tailwindcss": "^0.1.8",
    "start-server-and-test": "^1.14.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.0.23",
    "ts-jest": "^27.1.4",
    "ts-node": "^10.7.0",
    "typescript": "^4.6.3",
    "vitest": "^0.8.2"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "14"
  }
}
```

```json
// packageA package.json
{
  "name": "fuzzy-scrawl",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "author": "slackermorris",
  "repository": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "keywords": [
    "css",
    "typescript",
    "scss"
  ],
  "main": "./build/main.js",
  "module": "./build/main.js",
  "type": "module",
  "types": "./build/tsc/main.d.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "esbuild-browser:dev": "NODE_ENV=development node build esbuild-browser:dev",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.21",
    "@types/node": "^15.0.1",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.15",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.6",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.19.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.19.0",
    "esbuild": "^0.11.11",
    "esbuild-css-modules-plugin": "^2.3.2",
    "esbuild-plugin-css-modules": "^0.1.3",
    "esbuild-sass-plugin": "^2.2.6",
    "esbuild-style-plugin": "^1.6.0",
    "eslint": "^7.22.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "live-server": "^1.2.2",
    "sass": "^1.53.0",
    "ts-jest": "^26.5.4",
    "ts-node": "^9.1.1",
    "typedoc": "^0.20.35",
    "typescript": "^4.2.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "gsap": "^3.10.4",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Fuzzy is ESM so don’t use require. Maybe your project B has babel transpiling to commonjs?